# How to get background-url in Python?

Tags: python, css, selenium

I am trying to get background url property in Python with Selenium WebDriver. Works fine with 'color' and 'position' properties but not with 'background' or 'background-url'.

```
home = driver.find_element_by_id("link-home")
print(home.value_of_css_property("position"))
=> absolute
```

Can anyone help me?

This is the css:

```
#main-header a#link-home {
    background: url("data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAB8AAAATCAYAAABobNZCAAAAGXRFWHRTb2Z0d2FyZQBBZG9iZSBJbWFnZVJlYWR5ccllPAAAAOFJREFUeNpiPLRnNQMR4D8QM2KTsHUOYSAXMBFpMTKNLP6fgQLARKTFjDgcwEAry5Et5qeFA5iIsNgDiO9Baao6gImAxX5AvBGIhaC0H66ERw3LkS0OB2JQVmCDirFB+eHUcgATDosTgHgpksUMSA5YCpUHO+Dw3jX/KbUc2eI0IJ4PxMxQPgjPQmIzQ+XTKHUAE5rFOUA8E0l+JhJ/Jha5fGAhQ7YDGJFKuGogbkGXR7IoHUdKrwE6oJXSOG/BkfL/Q4MYV4nWQsvilWaAhVC04CkHaFq80hyMWj7yLAcIMADiujmyHco+MAAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==") no-repeat scroll 0px 0px transparent;
    left: 10px;
    padding-left: 23px;
    position: absolute;
    top: -102px;
    color: #DFEFFC;
}
```

Comment: Please provide the link to the webpage.

Comment: Why do you need the link to the webpage? I'm afraid I can't provide the link because the webpage itself is an intranet.

Comment: @bobafett it is probably webelement-specific - that's why it would nice to have a link to reproduce the problem - I've tried with http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_background and `element.value_of_css_property("background")` worked for me.

Comment: Hi @alecxe thanks for your answer. I tried the following code but it didn't work `driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_background")
body = driver.find_element_by_tag_name("body")
print(body.value_of_css_property("background")) => none`. In your code element is body?

Comment: @bobafett I've rolled back your question to the state it had before you edited a solution into it. Please do not do this. If you want to post your own solution, post it as an actual answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've reproduced the problem with getting `background` or `background-url` property in **firefox** (using firefox 35.0.1 and selenium 2.45).

Workaround that worked for me in Firefox:

```
print driver.execute_script("""
var element = arguments[0],
    style = element.currentStyle || window.getComputedStyle(element, false);

return style['background-image'];
""", body)
```

Demo:

```
>>> from selenium import webdriver
>>> 
>>> driver = webdriver.Firefox()
>>> driver.get("http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_background")
>>> 
>>> driver.switch_to.frame("iframeResult")
>>> 
>>> body = driver.find_element_by_tag_name("body")
>>> 
>>> print driver.execute_script("""
... var element = arguments[0],
...     style = element.currentStyle || window.getComputedStyle(element, false);
... 
... return style['background-image'];
... """, body)
url("http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/smiley.gif")
```

Or, just switch to `webdriver.Chrome()`.

Comment: Hi @alecxe, I get none as result since there is not 'background-image' property: `driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_background")
body = driver.find_element_by_tag_name("body")
print(driver.execute_script("""
var element = arguments[0],
    style = element.currentStyle || window.getComputedStyle(element, false);

return style['background-image'];
""", body)) => none` However if I replace 'background-image' by 'background' or 'background-url' and run again the result is a blank space. What am I doing wrong?